# why doesn't sem_wait block

Tags: c, semaphore

```
static int res1 = 0;
static int res2 = 0;
static int res3 = 0;

static int counter = 0;
static sem_t sem;



void * func_thread1(void *p)
{
    sleep(2);
    res1 = 1;
    printf("func_thread1\n");
    sem_post(&sem);
    return NULL;
}

void * func_thread2(void *p)
{
    sleep(2);
    res2 = 2;
    printf("func_thread2\n");
    sem_post(&sem);
    return NULL;
}

void * func_thread3(void *p)
{
    sem_wait(&sem);
    sem_wait(&sem);
    res3 = res1 + res2;
    printf("func_thread3\n");
    return NULL;
}




void main()
{
    sem_init(&sem, 0, counter);
    pthread_t pd1, pd2, pd3;
    pthread_create(&pd1, NULL, func_thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pd2, NULL, func_thread2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pd3, NULL, func_thread3, NULL);

    //pthread_join(pd3, NULL);

    printf("main_thread\n");
    printf("%d", res3);
}
```

I'm trying to understand how semaphore works.
I'm trying to make the `td3` block to wait for the `td1` and the `td2`.

In my opinion, the `sem_wait` will block twice. If the `sem_post`s in `func_thread1` and in `func_thread2` are executed, `func_thread3` could continue.

However, it doesn't work unless I add `pthread_join(td3, NULL)` in `main`. I think the join is not necessary because `sem_wait` can block.

So `pthread_join` is necessary or I use semaphore incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_join` is mandatory in your implementation.

Otherwise your process finishes (ie. main returns), and all tasks (ie. threads) are killed before thread 3 prints anything.

Comment: sem_wait() decrements (locks) the semaphore pointed to by sem.  If
       the semaphore's value is greater than zero, then the decrement
       proceeds, and the function returns, immediately.  If the semaphore
       currently has the value zero, then the call blocks until either it
       becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e., the semaphore value
       rises above zero), or a signal handler interrupts the call.

Comment: You see, "if the semaphore currently has the value zero, then the call blocks...". What does block mean here?

Comment: It blocks the execution of the thread that is calling `sem_wait`, not the whole process or other tasks.